# Odd errors when using party package "contrasts cannot be applied ...." and "object of type closure...."

Tags: r

I am using the [`party`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/party/index.html) package.

When I run:

```
tree1 <- mob(incarcerated~priors+opens+concrearr+postrearr+anyrearr+postconvfel+postconvmis+
     ag_vfo+ag_cla2+in_custody |PRIOR_FELONY_ARREST ,
             data = jamaal, 
             control = ctrl, 
             model = glinearModel, 
             family = binomial)
```

I get the error

```
Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) :   
contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels
```

But I checked and every factor variable has at least 2 levels.

I then tried a much simpler tree

```
treetest <- mob(incarcerated~priors|in_custody, 
                data = jamaal, 
                control = ctrl,
                model = glinearModel, 
                family = binomial)
```

and got one of the infamous R error messages

```
Error: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
```

Any help appreciated

UPDATE
I found the source of the first error (it was a problem with how I was using factor()) but not the second. Also, `rpart` works on the same data with no problem.

The data are confidential, but I will check with the client if posting a small subset is OK

FURTHER UPDATE
Here is an small example with made up data:

```
priors <- c(rep('Y', 5), rep('N', 5))
incarcerated <- rep(c('Y', 'N'), 5)
in_custody <- rep(c(rep('Y', 3), rep('N', 2)),2)
testdata <- data.frame(cbind(priors, incarcerated, in_custody))
treetest <- mob(incarcerated~priors|in_custody, data = testdata, 
   model = glinearModel, family = binomial)
```

gives the same error.

Comment: Can you give us a reproducible example ... ?

Comment: If your data is confidential, you can also create a mockup dataset that reproduces the problem. In that way confidentiality is not problem.

Comment: I added some invented data to the question

Comment: So, you're saying that the `mob()` refuses to cooperate, eh?  Try `(..., omerta = FALSE)`.  ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`party` is looking for the *results* of a `binomial()` call, rather than the function `binomial` or the string `"binomial"`.  (In my opinion the `glm()` function in base R has made things very confusing by accepting any of these three as acceptable variants.)

```
priors <- c(rep('Y', 5), rep('N', 5))
incarcerated <- rep(c('Y', 'N'), 5)
in_custody <- rep(c(rep('Y', 3), rep('N', 2)),2)
testdata <- data.frame(cbind(priors, incarcerated, in_custody))

library(party)
treetest <- mob(incarcerated~priors|in_custody, data = testdata,
                model = glinearModel, family = binomial())
```

In hindsight, this error message is at least somewhat informative -- it tells us to look for a function that it is being passed somewhere that R expects an object that has elements that can be extracted ...

Comment: Thanks @Ben. Maybe that's a somewhat informative error to you, but not to me!

Comment: Ben -- Nice point about the error message.  @PeterFlom -- First look at `typeof(mean)` or `typeof(library)`, and then try subsetting a function (e.g. `mean[1]` or `library$sub`) to see what Ben's getting at. From now on it'll be an informative message for you as well!